# iOS 8 scan credit card event

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ios8, mobile-safari

On our shop there's a credit card form that the user fills out. For readability purposes, we auto format the credit card number with spaces every four character. We also validate the credit card, to check that the number is valid and to check that we accept that particular credit card. The user is shown a green check mark if it's OK, and a red cross if it's invalid or not accepted.

When using the scan credit card feature in iOS8, the credit card info is filled out. However, since neither keyup or keydown is fired the credit card isn't validated.

Is there any event that is fired when scanning a credit card in iOS 8? I've tried to check using webkits `monitorEvents` but it doesn't seem to exist in iOS.